# How to sum up Objects with same name within ObservableList<>

Tags: java, javafx, observable, addition

I've made a TableView which is filled with Ingredient Objects from a Database. I want to check if there are Ingredient Objects with the same name and unit and if yes sum up their amount to one Ingredient Object.

I tried to use 2 nested for-loops and check check the conditions.
Say for example I have 2 identical Ingredient Objects in my ObservableList and i populate my TableView with the code down below, I get the Ingredients as they were before plus summed up.

Relevant Part of Controller Class:

```
@FXML 
    void loadData(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{
//      System.out.println(menuList.size());
        ObservableList<ObservableList<Ingredients>> result = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Ingredients> all = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            for(String s : menuList) {
                result.add(DBUtils.getIngredById(DBUtils.getContent(s)));
            }
            for(ObservableList<Ingredients> obs : result) {
                for(Ingredients i : obs) {
                    all.add(i);
                }
            }
            ObservableList<Ingredients> asdad = mergeList(all);
            loadTable(asdad);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in loadTable()\n");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

private ObservableList<Ingredients> mergeList(ObservableList<Ingredients> all) {
    ObservableList<Ingredients> newList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for(Ingredients i : all) {
        for(Ingredients m : all) {
            if(all.indexOf(i) != all.indexOf(m)) {
                if(i.getIngred().equals(m.getIngred())) {
                    if(i.getUnit().equals(m.getUnit())) {
                        newList.add(sumUpIng(i, m));
                    }
                }
            }else {
                newList.add(m);
            }
        }

    }
    return newList;
}

private Ingredients sumUpIng(Ingredients i, Ingredients s) {
    Ingredients ing = new Ingredients();
    ing.setAmount(i.getAmount() + s.getAmount());
    ing.setUnit(i.getUnit());
    ing.setIngred(i.getIngred());

    return ing;
}

private void loadTable(ObservableList<Ingredients> data) {
    tblShopping.setItems(data);
}
```

Ingredients Class
https://pastebin.com/N35LeDf4

```
public class Ingredients {

    private IntegerProperty id;
    private DoubleProperty amount;
    private StringProperty unit;
    private StringProperty ingred;

    public Ingredients() {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        this.amount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.unit = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.ingred = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: `all.indexOf(i) != all.indexOf(i)` should be `all.indexOf(i) != all.indexOf(m)` I think

Comment: You are right. Now the ObservableList doesn't multiply itself anymore but still don't sum up

Comment: @fabian I replaced my == with .equals().. above the controller class is the result

Comment: BTW: If you use a indexed loop your nested loops would become more efficient. `indexOf` runs in `O(n)` which means your implementation runs in `O(n³)`; using indices would reduce this to `O(n²)`: `for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < all.size(); outerIndex++) { Ingredients i = all.get(outerIndex); ... }` (Not that you should implement the logic like this; just as a hint for the future...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested loop won't work properly. One reason for this is that it's executed for every combination of indices. For inequal indices the loop is executed twice. Furthermore there may be more than 2 ingredients with the same `unit`/`ingred` property combinations. The best way of doing this seems to be storing the indices of the `Map` mapping from a combination of `unit`/`ingred` key to `Integer` values containing the value containing the index of the element with this combination in the result list.

```
/**
 * Class implementing hashCode/equals based on ingred and unit
 * for use as key in a HashMap
 */
private static class IngredientWrapper {
    private final Ingredients ingredient;

    private IngredientWrapper(Ingredients ingredient) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(ingredient.getIngred(), ingredient.getUnit());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        IngredientWrapper other = (IngredientWrapper) obj;
        return Objects.equals(ingredient.getIngred(), other.ingredient.getIngred())
                && Objects.equals(ingredient.getUnit(), other.ingredient.getUnit());
    }

}

private static ObservableList<Ingredients> mergeList(ObservableList<Ingredients> all) {
    ObservableList<Ingredients> newList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    Map<IngredientWrapper, Integer> indices = new HashMap<>();
    Integer index = 0;

    for(Ingredients ingredient : all) {
        Integer listIndex = indices.putIfAbsent(new IngredientWrapper(ingredient), index);
        if (listIndex == null) {
            // combination not yet in the list
            newList.add(ingredient);
            index++;
        } else {
            // combination already in the list
            Ingredients listIngredient = newList.get(listIndex);
            listIngredient.setAmount(listIngredient.getAmount() + ingredient.getAmount());
        }

    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: This solved my Problem, thanks. I understood what your code is doing but when are the overwritten methods hashCode and equals executed?

Comment: @jje32dys `HashMap`s use `hashCode` to determine how to store the entries (makes for fast lookup). The following graphic should illustrate the general concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#/media/File:Hash_table_4_1_1_0_0_1_0_LL.svg The important thing to keep in mind here is that for `HashMap` to consider 2 keys the same, the `hashCode` results need to be the same and `key1.equals(key2)` returns true (or both are `null`).

Comment: Okay I got this. How do I have to change the above code when I want to merge two Ingredients {[200.0,gr,Potatoes],[1.0,kg,Potatoes]} with the same name but different units?

Comment: @jje32dys This makes things way simpler. You can drop the `IngredientWrapper` class and use a `Map<String, Integer> indices` storing the indices by `Ingredients.getIngred`. Of course the code in the `else` block needs to be adjusted accordingly.